# How tensorflow Variable store in Memory

Tags: variables, memory, tensorflow

when I define a Variable use Python, for example:

```html
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a variable.
w = tf.Variable(<initial-value>, name=<optional-name>)

# Use the variable in the graph like any Tensor.
y = tf.matmul(w, ...another variable or tensor...)

# The overloaded operators are available too.
z = tf.sigmoid(w + y)

# Assign a new value to the variable with `assign()` or a related method.
w.assign(w + 1.0)
w.assign_add(1.0)
```

I want to know how tensorflow allocate memory for Variable w. 
Thanks~

Comment: Python will allocate memory dynamically, using http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/ this logic.  Not sure if that's what you're asking?  Why do you want to know?

Comment: @JeffUK, thankyou~  I read tensorflow code these days. "Variable" in that snippet is a tensorflow syntax, not the python syntax. I want to know when tensorflow "see" Variable in user`s code, how tensorfow allocate memory for it.

Comment: @JeffUK, no, the question seems to be explicitely about the TensorFlow variable. TF builds a graph that is run later on. The allocation of that memory happens in C++ code below and not in python. What is shown here is only the building of the graph.

Comment: @Mayou36 Sounds like you have the start of an answer there, why not post it?  To be honest I'm sure after nearly 2 years OP will be thankful for any insight you can provide!

Comment: @JeffUK, unfortunately, I don't know the _how_. I know where, I know that, but the _how_ exactly is also a secret to me. Unfortunately...OP, can you may provide some clarification on _what_ exaclty you want to know? Your code snippet contains a few different things and _does_ actually not do anything yet.